# How are viruses in vaccines weakened in a laboratory

Tags: homework

I would like to know how viruses in vaccines are weakened or attenuated in a laboratory

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! Can You share what efforts you have done in finding the answer. Low-research effort questions are likely to be closed.

Comment: Short answer: You take viruses from humans and grow them in a different organism until it no longer elicits pathogenicity to human, through generations adapting to a different organism. Typically chicken embryos.

Comment: You can remove either the genetic material of the virus, or its functional proteins and then inject it.